# React-native-Firebase: “auth/network-request-failed”

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Describe your issue here

My Application is in production and the verification works well, but I have a problem with the verification of phone numbers on phones Samsung and other with run Android 5.X , 4.X.

The execution of this code:

```
firebase
         .auth ()
         .verifyPhoneNumber (phoneFullNumber)
```

generate the error: `[auth / network-request-failed]` A network error

NB: Our application in production on google play
NB: this problem is encountered by some android phones any version included
NB: The telephones which encounter this problem have internet which works well and Google Play